# Reading command line flags from file

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script that allows users to provide additional docker build args using a config file.

```
BUILD_ARGS=
source ./userconfig.sh
docker build $BUILD_ARGS ...
```

In userconfig.sh,

```
USERID=$(id -u)
BUILD_ARGS="--build-arg=\"USERID=$USERID\" --build-arg\"SECONDARG=somethingelse\""
```

I see that the args are being single quoted when executed

```
docker build '--build-arg="USERID=1000"' '--build-arg="SECONDARG=somethingelse"' ...
```

I have tried using arrays instead of string.

```
BUILD_ARGS=()
BUILD_ARGS=( --build-arg=\"USERID=$USERID\" --build-arg\"SECONDARG=somethingelse\" )
docker build "${BUILD_ARGS[@]}" ...
```

I get the same error.

How can i fix this?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia) (and many others) (but ignore all suggestions involving `eval` -- it is a massive bug magnet). Also, see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: apologies on the duplicate - I could not quite figure out what to search for.

Comment: I don't use `docker`, but I doubt that `docker build` wants to see quotes in the `--build-arg` option. This would be a pretty unusualy design.

Comment: Regarding "I get the same error." - [edit] your question to show the exact error message. If you ever have any software (or anything else in life) giving you an error message and you want help from anyone to solve the problem, telling them what the error message is is an important part of that process.

Comment: @EdMorton error - incorrect behavior. The args were being single quoted. I had mentioned it in the lines before, and shown how they were being quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array. Do not escape specially in an array, use it normally like you would on command line.

```
BUILD_ARGS=( --build-arg="USERID=$USERID" --build-arg"SECONDARG=somethingelse" )
docker build "${BUILD_ARGS[@]}" ...
```